# RMI Java | Probleme with IP binding and Problem with Security Manager

Tags: java, rmi, rcp

**Problem 1** resolved !

I am confused with the following problem I am doing a project for my school about RMI in Java and I put an object in RMIRegistery

```
public static void bindObjectToRMIRegistry(Object obj,String name) throws AccessException, RemoteException {
    System.out.println("<< IN ServerHelper.bindObjectToRMIRegistry() >>");
    if(getRMIRegistru() != null) {
        System.out.println("Binding to registry: "+getRMIRegistru().toString());
        getRMIRegistru().rebind(name, (Remote) obj);
    }else {
        System.out.println("No registry to bind");
    }
}
```

In log I get the following message:

> Binding to registry: RegistryImpl_Stub[UnicastRef [liveRef:
>   [endpoint:**192.168.56.1:9005**,objID:[0:0:0, 0]]]]
>
> The port is good 9005, but the IP, it's not the good one and I have no
>   ideea where does he get this IP. I also tried to set the HOST for rmi
>   to my localhost **192.168.1.2** but it keeps using this address
>   **192.168.56.1:9005**

Is there something I am missing in configurations ?

**Problem 2**

```
Registry registery = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("192.168.1.2",9005);
IHello hi = (IHello) registery.lookup("HI");
```

I get: *RemoteException error: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Interfaces.IHello (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)*

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have multiple network interfaces e.g. LAN, WLAN, virtual to handle VMs, etc. You can check this by running `ipconfig` (Windows) or `ifconfig` (Linux).

Specify the right IP when binding RMI. Java can't guess which one you want if you have multiple:

```
Naming.rebind("//192.168.1.2/rmi", new RMI());
```

Comment: OMG you are totally right @Karol Dowbecki thank you so much for your help, and now I have another problem if you kindly know the answer.Now at retrieving it i get the following error RemoteException error: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Interfaces.IHello (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled). I can see it  RegistryImpl_Stub[UnicastRef [liveRef: [endpoint:[192.168.1.2:9005](remote),objID:[0:0:0, 0]]]] that it's bind to the IP and PORT corectly, but now i have no ideea about Security Manager